# How can I find the actual source code that runs when I invoke s->method->ssl_write in OpenSSL on my machine?

Tags: c, openssl

OpenSSL has a method named `SSL_write`, described here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_write.html

The source code for this method is available in the sources available here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl in `ssl/ssl_lib.c`:

```
int SSL_write(SSL *s, const void *buf, int num)
{
    int ret;
    size_t written;

    if (num < 0) {
        ERR_raise(ERR_LIB_SSL, SSL_R_BAD_LENGTH);
        return -1;
    }

    ret = ssl_write_internal(s, buf, (size_t)num, &written);
    /* more code omitted */
```

And `ssl_write_internal` does some checks before it eventually yields to:

```
int ssl_write_internal(SSL *s, const void *buf, size_t num, size_t *written)
{
    /* checking and async logic omitted */
        return s->method->ssl_write(s, buf, num, written);
```

That's where I get stuck, though - I can't seem to find a function named `ssl_write` anywhere that actually performs the writing.

I know OpenSSL has a lot of metaprogramming and indirection involved. Can you help me figure out where we jump in the code when `ssl_write` is invoked? If this involves assumptions about a particular TLS version or OS, let's assume Linux and TLS v1.2.

Comment: "I can't seem to find a function named ssl_write anywhere" function *pointer*. The function isn't (necessarily) named `ssl_write`.

Comment: Attach a debugger, set a breakpoint in the function and look at the backtrace?

Comment: Edited the question title to make this more clear

Comment: Alternatively if you can only do source analysis then you'll need to be more creative in your search. The function is within a struct so it's very possible that it's statically initialised in multiple places where the function it is init to may be named anything (so possibly no reference to `ssl_write` at all) . One example is `methods_sslp` in `bio_ssl.c` (that one does name its function `ssl_write`). But using the runtime method with the debugger will be faster and more accurate if you can use that.

Comment: Sorry, but it could be impossible to do with source analysis. `ssl_write` can point to anything. You will have to use a debugger or know SSL in and out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote me on that, but... ;-)

`ssl_write` is member of `ssl_method_st` struct. `ssl_local.h` has three macros that create instances of that struct. Let's focus on `IMPLEMENT_tls_meth_func` (see [ssl_local.h:2234](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/ssl_local.h#L2234)). It uses `ssl3_write` for that member and this is not an argument of the macro. `ssl3_write` is actually a function (see [s3_lib.c:4422](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/s3_lib.c#L4422)):

```c
clear_sys_error();
if (s->s3.renegotiate)
    ssl3_renegotiate_check(s, 0);

return s->method->ssl_write_bytes(s, SSL3_RT_APPLICATION_DATA, buf, len,
                                  written);
```

The same applies to `ssl_write_bytes`, which seem to be doing the hard part, based on its length of 315 lines :-) (see [rec_layer_s3.c:349](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c#L349)).